# NotSerializableException: How can i save ClipData to a File?

Tags: android, exception, serialization, clipboard

I want to save Clipboard data to a file. This is the code in my Activity class:

```
ClipData clip = mClipboard.getPrimaryClip();

FileOutputStream fos;
ObjectOutputStream os;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(clip);
    os.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this exception:

06-26 20:20:03.556: W/System.err(24228): java.io.NotSerializableException: android.content.ClipData
06-26 20:20:03.556: W/System.err(24228):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
06-26 20:20:03.556: W/System.err(24228):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
06-26 20:20:03.556: W/System.err(24228):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
06-26 20:20:03.556: W/System.err(24228):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)

As ClipData is an Android class, how can I remove this exception by Serializing ?

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: What makes you think that `ClipData` supports being persisted this way?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can't I ? Not sure about it. I needed to save the data in a secure way , so i want to store it to a file and then change the clipboard data. Am i doing something wrong? Or is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: "I needed to save the data in a secure way" -- serialized Java objects are not secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only primitive types can be serialized. ClipDate not implements Serializable interface. So, you can't do this. But you can create your own object. It should implement Serializable interface and contain fields with primitive types, such as String. You can fill them with necessary data from ClipDate object and serialize your object. Then you can deserialize your object and restore initial ClipDate oject.

Comment: This would not solve my problem. If I store the data as primitive types for ClipData then I may not be able to use its functions for ClipData.Item etc to get the text coerced etc. I wont be able to paste exact data later that was copied before !

Comment: @Sneha: "I may not be able to use its functions for ClipData.Item etc to get the text coerced etc" -- create new instances of `ClipData` and `ClipData.Item` from the persisted data, using their respective constructors.